# Changing file encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: php, encoding

I am creating an xml and .blm file from one set of data, I am taking text data in iso-8859-1 and converting it to UTF-8 using

```
$desc = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $desc);
```

This works great for the XML, but those getting the BLM have asked that it be in ANSI. How can I convert the .blm file to ANSI, is there anyway to do it when I am writing to the file? or after I have created the file?

Comment: Liam, you should confirm with your BLM users that the "ANSI" they want is indeed "Windows-1252". ANSI is just an alias for the actual codepage, it means different things for users in different countries (e.g., for Japanese, Ukrainian and British users "ANSI" may be 3 completely different things).

Comment: @Constantin - which is funny, given that ANSI is an acronym for American National Standards Institute ... and yes, I suppose for other things as well.

Comment: @Anon, Quite :) Still, there is no such thing as *the* "ANSI" codepage, or *the* "ISO" standard :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, ANSI is referred to as Windows-1252 (or CP-1252):

```
$desc = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "WINDOWS-1252", $desc);
```

Comment: deleting my earlier comment: WINDOWS-1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1